# How can i solve a stuck Gitlab CI pipeline?

Tags: gitlab

I'm using  GitLab CI shell as the executor.

I made an.gitlab-ci.yml, and I determined my code in it when im done
the pipeline got stuck, and I don't know to resolve it.

[the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fo96.png)

[the code I use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dfEG.png)

Comment: Most likely because you've set `tags: - docker` and you don't have a runner available with that tag set. Either remove the tag from the job configuration or register a runner with the tag.

Answer (score 1):

A pipeline will be declared as *stuck* when no requested runner can be available to run it.

Your job configuration requests a runner with the tag `docker`. Based on the fact that your pipeline is stuck, this tells me that you do not have a GitLab runner available to your project that has a `docker` tag on it.

To fix this, you'll either have to remove the tag from your job configuration or [register a runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/) with the `docker` tag (or add the docker tag to an existing runner).

Answer (score 0):

Alright I removed the tags, and it did solve that problem, but now I still get a failed status where i don't know what to do

[image]

Comment: i solved this problem using this solution https://techdirectarchive.com/2021/10/05/gitlab-runner-there-has-been-a-runner-system-failure-job-failed-system-failure-prepare-the-environment-failed-to-start-the-process-exec-pwsh/   ps thanks for sytech for resolving my other problem

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve your issue and thanks for sharing your experience with that secondary issue with others. If you have a new issue that comes up, it's usually best to ask a new question. If there's an answer that resolved your question, please consider accepting it as the solution to your question. Welcome to the site!